# Login using Mechanize gem

Tags: ruby, authentication, mechanize

```
My code is this


 require 'mechanize'
  obj=Mechanize.new
  a.get("http://cafedepoca.com/submit_data?name=test&email=test@mail.com&pass=mypassword&prof_type=30&api_key=mykey") do |d|
  d.user='testuser'
  d.password='mypassword'
  end.click_button
```

It return and an **error.Net::HTTPUnauthorized** .If any another way to fill credential in popup box.If any other gem is present the suggest me.

Comment: what is 'a' in your case?

Comment: When i fill the value it returns ouath Net::HTTPUnauthorized error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked for http://cafedepoca.com and it prompts with BasicAuthentication. You have to enter it first.

```
 require 'mechanize'
 a=Mechanize.new
 a.auth('username','password') # fix this line with correct login and password for BasicAuth  
 a.get("http://cafedepoca.com/submit_data?name=test&email=test@mail.com&pass=mypassword&prof_type=30&api_key=mykey").click_button
```

It should work this way.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [Mechanize#auth](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize.html#method-i-auth) or [Mechanize#add_auth](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize.html#method-i-add_auth) to pass Basic Authentication.

```
require 'mechanize'

USERNAME = "XXXXXXXX"
PASSWORD = "YYYYYYYY"

agent = Mechanize.new
agent.auth(USERNAME, PASSWORD)
agent.get("http://cafedepoca.com/submit_data?name=test&email=test@mail.com&pass=mypassword&prof_type=30&api_key=mykey")
```